# How to make dgeni/ngdoc generate hash-bang links for ngrouter?

Tags: angular-routing, ngdoc

I'm creating docs using ng-router in non-html5 mode.
All links should be converted to href="#!/path".
By default tag {@link} creates href="path".

Is ths behaviour configurable?

Answer (score 1):

What i've found is, that `ngdoc` is using `link` filter.

You can override that filter with 2 simple steps.

Create a file (`./filters/link.js`) with the following content:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

    module.exports = function() {
      return {
        name: 'link',
        process: function(url, title, doc) {
          return _.template('{@link ${url} ${title} }')({ url: '#!/'+url, title: title });
        }
      };
    };
```

After you have to register (override) it. In your dgeni configuration file put this:

```
...
.config(function(templateEngine, getInjectables) {

  templateEngine.filters = templateEngine.filters.concat(getInjectables([
    require('./filters/link')
  ]));

})
...
```

This will register a new filter under the name `link`.  Since it's running after ngdoc configuration, it will override existing `link` filter.

Hope it helps.